# Pytorch Clustering of Model Parameters with high dimensional data

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to cluster the model parameters to separate benign and malicious ones into 2 clusters using kmeans. However, as it is a high dimensional data (approx 300k parameters), I am getting an error which says:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (10, 1) + inhomogeneous part.

local_dict.append(torch.stack([client_models[i].state_dict()[k]],0).cpu().detach().numpy())
kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=2,random_state=0).fit(local_dict)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (10, 1) + inhomogeneous part.
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: local_model=client_models[i].state_dict()
for k in local_model.keys():
            local_dict.append(torch. Stack([client_models[i].state_dict()[k]],0).cpu().detach().numpy())
kmeans=KMeans(n_clusters=2,random_state=0).fit(local_dict)